# URL opening fine in web browser, but giving error when opened using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I am trying to hit the following URL using Qt: "https://www.cyclestreets.net/api/journey.json?itinerarypoints=13.417365,52.513381%7C13.438596,52.519854&key=cdccf13997d59e70&plan=balanced&reporterrors=1&speed=20". If I hit it in a web browser, it does give some response (please try it yourself). However I receive the error `QNetworkReply::NetworkError(UnknownNetworkError)` when I try to hit the same using the following code:

```
QUrl url("https://www.cyclestreets.net/api/journey.json");
QMap<QString, QString> queryStrings;
queryStrings["key"] = "cdccf13997d59e70";
queryStrings["reporterrors"] = QLatin1Char('1');
queryStrings["plan"] = settings[QStringLiteral("plan")].toString();
if (queryStrings["plan"].isEmpty()) {
    queryStrings["plan"] = QStringLiteral("balanced");
}
queryStrings["speed"] = settings[QStringLiteral("speed")].toString();
if (queryStrings["speed"].isEmpty()) {
    queryStrings["speed"] = QStringLiteral("20");
}
GeoDataCoordinates::Unit const degree = GeoDataCoordinates::Degree;
QString itinerarypoints;
itinerarypoints.append(QString::number(route->source().longitude(degree), 'f', 6) + QLatin1Char(',') + QString::number(route->source().latitude(degree), 'f', 6));
for ( int i=1; i<route->size(); ++i ) {
    itinerarypoints.append(QLatin1Char('|') +  QString::number(route->at(i).longitude(degree), 'f', 6) + QLatin1Char(',') + QString::number(route->at(i).latitude(degree), 'f', 6));
}
queryStrings["itinerarypoints"] = itinerarypoints;

QUrlQuery urlQuery;
for( const QString& key: queryStrings.keys()){
    urlQuery.addQueryItem(key, queryStrings.value(key));
}
url.setQuery( urlQuery);

m_request.setUrl( url );
m_request.setRawHeader( "User-Agent", HttpDownloadManager::userAgent( "Browser", "CycleStreetsRunner" ) );
QNetworkReply *reply = m_networkAccessManager.get( m_request );
connect( reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
         this, SLOT(handleError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), Qt::DirectConnection );

void CycleStreetsRunner::handleError( QNetworkReply::NetworkError error )
{
    qDebug() << "Error: " << error;
}
```

Any idea how can this possibly happen? How is it possible that the exact same URL is giving valid response in web browser, but giving network error in Qt? Any type of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have only Qt4 installed and not Qt5 required for `QUrlQuery`. So I can suggest only to debug your code step by step or insert below `url.setQuery( urlQuery);` the line `qDebug() << url.toEncoded();` to see the final encoded url in console.

Comment: Well, `QNetworkRequest` doesn't really have a `toEncoded()` function, but doing `m_request.url()` does print `QUrl("https://www.cyclestreets.net/api/journey.json?itinerarypoints=13.417365,52.513381%7C13.438596,52.519854&key=cdccf13997d59e70&plan=balanced&reporterrors=1&speed=20")` which is the correct URL I am hitting in the web browser and getting some valid response.

Comment: Indeed, the url is 100% correct. So the unknown error must be caused by something different. Perhaps the request with the defined raw header is not accepted by the server. I suggest to install free tool Wireshark, trace the communication of a browser with the server and next the communication of your application with the server and compare the requests. Perhaps you can see in Wireshark traces what is the difference causing the unknown error.